# Java Game - How to give movement to enemies?

Tags: java, game-physics

I'm doing a shooter game and adding a lot of enemies with an array, and then giving them a random position on the map, but i dont know how to make them move after they reach their postions. This is my Enemy class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import java.util.Random;
public class Enemy {

private static final Random r = new Random();
int x = r.nextInt(36);
int y = r.nextInt(24);
Vector2 vect = new Vector2(x,y);
float ROTATION_SPEED = 500;

    public Follower(float SPEED, float rotation, float width, float height,
                    Vector2 position) {
            super(SPEED, rotation, width, height, position);
    }

    public void advance(float delta, Ship ship) {
        if(rotation > 360)
                rotation -= 360;

            position.lerp(vect, delta);

        rotation += delta * ROTATION_SPEED;


        super.update(ship);

        //Edited: i forget to put this lines:
        if(vect.equals(this.getPosition())){
        x = r.nextInt(36);
        y = r.nextInt(24);

        }
}
```

What kind of method should i implement in this class to make them move x/y values after a certain time?

Comment: You need a timer to animate the movements.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Thread.sleep without Multithreading, the whole game will freeze. But you can also solve it with a Timer and TimerTask it's easy especially for Beginners (You can add this to your code before):

```
import java.util.Timer;

import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Enemy{

    Timer t;

    public Enemy(){ //in your constructor

        t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
            public void run(){
                /*here the code for the movement, e.g:
                x += 5;
                y += 5;*/
            }


        }, delay, speed); //delay is after which time it should start usually delay is 0, speed is the time in ms e.g. 9 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep is the way to sleep for some time before doing further processing. You will do good to start looking at multi-threading in Java to solve such kind of problems easily. You can begin here :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

For immediate solution, just write Thread.sleep() in a while loop.

Comment: While Thread.sleep() in a while loop is certainly nessissary a full multithreaded solution might be a bit over the top for something like this. I'm currently writing a 3D game and (excluding graphics card stuff which isn't true multithreading) I've still not yet found multithreading to be nessissary

Comment: Thread isn't working in my game, if i use it the whole game freezes until the thread is finished.
By the way, i forget to put some code lines in the question, that gives the random position to my enemies.

Comment: @MaderaRoberson - that's why you need to look at multi threading immediately. In Java 6/7 you need to start with the basic Thread and runnable and then you can look at ExecutorService for an easy way to manage your threads. Aldo Future, is a great way to create async kind of operations without getting into too much detail.  Without any MT option, you will end up writing code which will be ST and will wait for some form of user input. For war kind of games, where enemies and vehicles need to move on their own, it's always going to be MT environment.